# Global calendars in Formula

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I have the following problem and can not find a solution on google.

```
ProjDateAdd([Start9];[Duration9];"myCal")
```

The formula is in the field finish9 and only works if the global calendar "myCal" is used in the current Project. Is there a way to load or use a global calendar with formulas?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding a dummy task that uses the calendar you want so that that global calendar is now available in your schedule.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. It Works.